# Function for adding parameters in IAM policy

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I have been working on a boto script for creating an IAM user policy from a function. I want to add the region, instance_type and ebs_volume restriction, inside the policy. I want the output to be in the json format. I am not sure how to proceed with it.Name of the file is template_function.py
This is the function

```
def create_aws_iam_policy_template(**template):
  print()

create_aws_iam_policy_template(region = "us-east-1", instance_type = "t2.micro", volume_size = "12")
```

This is the policy which is store in another file in the same directory "metatemplate.py"

```
    import json 
    import template_function
    import boto3
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
                "Resource": [
                    f"arn:aws:ec2:{region}::instance/*",
                    f"arn:aws:ec2:{region}::network-interface/*",
                    f"arn:aws:ec2:{region}::key-pair/*",
                    f"arn:aws:ec2:{region}::security-group/*",
                    f"arn:aws:ec2:{region}::subnet/*",
                    f"arn:aws:ec2:{region}::volume/*",
                    f"arn:aws:ec2:{region}::image/ami-*"
                ],
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:NumericLessThanEquals": {
                        "ec2:VolumeSize": f"{volume_size}"
                    },
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:InstanceType": f"{instance_type}"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                    "ec2:StartInstances",
                    "ec2:StopInstances"
                ],
                "Resource": f"arn:aws:ec2:{region}::instance/*",
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:InstanceType": f"{region}"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:Describe*",
                    "ec2:GetConsole*",
                    "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                    "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
                    "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                    "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                    "ec2:CreateKeyPair"
                ],
                "Resource": "*",
                "Condition": {
                    "DateGreaterThan": {
                        "aws:CurrentTime": f"{start_time}"
                    },
                    "DateLessThanEquals": {
                        "aws:CurrentTime": f"{end_time}"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    } 
    response = iam.create_policy(
       PolicyName='GoodPolicy',
       PolicyDocument=json.dumps(some_policy)
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Python object that has the same members as you want to see in the JSON, then in your code `import json` and call `json.dumps(your_python_object)`.  That will turn your object into a JSON string.

Then call the [create_policy API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_policy) and pass in the string you get from json.dumps as the `PolicyDocument` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. Below is one

```
    import json
    from jinja2 import Template

    policy = '''
    {  
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::instance/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::network-interface/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::key-pair/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::security-group/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::subnet/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::volume/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::image/ami-*"
                ],
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:NumericLessThanEquals": {
                        "ec2:VolumeSize": "{{volume_size}}"
                    },
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:InstanceType": "{{instance_type}}"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                    "ec2:StartInstances",
                    "ec2:StopInstances"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::instance/*",
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:InstanceType": "{{region}}"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:Describe*",
                    "ec2:GetConsole*",
                    "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                    "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
                    "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                    "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                    "ec2:CreateKeyPair"
                ],
                "Resource": "*",
                "Condition": {
                    "DateGreaterThan": {
                        "aws:CurrentTime": "{{start_time}}"
                    },
                    "DateLessThanEquals": {
                        "aws:CurrentTime": "{{end_time}}"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    '''

    tm = Template(policy)
    parsed_policy = tm.render(egion='us-east-1',start_time='1-2-3', end_time='3-4-5', volume_size='2', instance_type='t2.micro')
    print(json.dumps(parsed_policy))
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot, but I wanted the policy and function to be in different files. Is that possible?, because in the future I would have to convert the function into a lambda function, I will also be creating a config module to double check .

Comment: The name for the file with function is template_function.py. I have made the changes in the question as well.

Comment: take a look [here](http://zetcode.com/python/jinja/) multiple ways of handling the templates.